# This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature"

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-permissions, facebook-business-sdk

I am using facebook's business onboarding API for my clients to create Facebook ads. The Facebook marketing API version is **v4.0** and we are using "**PHP facebook graph SDK**" for all the API calls. My application flow for creating a Facebook campaign is as follows:

```
1)Create a Child Business Manager for a client Facebook account  
2)Set Up Payment Method    
3)Get the Child System User Token 
4)Fetch the System User's ID    5)Get the Funding Source ID   
6)Create a New Ad Account with the Default Funding Source    7)Add
the System User as an Admin to the New Ad Account    8)Claim a page
for  business as an AGENCY,[Document link]
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/asset-management#pages-claim)
9)Assign system to the page,[Document link](
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/asset-management#pages-add-people)
```

Before assigning a system user to the page  I am calling GET API
`<https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/{PAGE_ID}/assigned_users?business={business_id}>`  for reading specific permission for the Facebook page But this API call results in error "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature. Refer to `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages` and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS for details."

I am using system user access token for this API and I have already provided manage_pages permission for tokens. What is the reason for this error? Do I need 'Page Public Content Access' permission as well?

Comment: you have to get privileges of manage_pages from facebook developer console if you dont have then you have to get access from from facebook before accessing

Comment: I already have manage_pages permission

Comment: _“Do I need 'Page Public Content Access' permission as well?”_ - well that’s what https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/assigned_users/#feature-permissions suggest at least. Kinda makes sense, I suppose - because currently, your system user does not have admin access to the page already. So this query has to be treated as a “public” one then.

Comment: @JyotiTambare Dis you get solved this issue, I need a help If so